# Use placeholder (or generate unique id) using wiremock with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, uuid, wiremock

I'm using JMeter for load test, and mocking external service using wiremock.

I'm using `JSON` files to mimic the responses from those external service, 
one of the

```
{
"response":"459ada78-842b-4229-b9d8-4dcdb52aa738"
}
```

It is very simple response with only 1 UUID field, the problem is on my side this is must be unique everytime i call the service

Is there any way to regenerate that id from the mock file or using some kind of placeholder instead of static value

Comment: Have you had a look at the random helper for UUID [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#random-value-helper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JMeter's [__UUID](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function

```
${__UUID()}
```

> will return UUIDs with this format : c69e0dd1-ac6b-4f2b-8d59-5d4e8743eecd