# I want to give a unique dynamic value as a variable in tha path of a jmeter post request

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a post request that takes a variable in the url path and for every loop the variable must be unique.

As I wanted the post request for n no of times I have placed it in a loop controller, I can't use a csv file or any file upload externally to give different values

The sample post request goes somthing like

[https://demo.apple.com/users/${deviceId}](https://demo.apple.com/users/$%7BdeviceId%7D)

And the body is

{

"type":"device",

"Name":"acb"

}

As it is a post request it has body also, I can't add deviceid under parameters.

So is there any way to create a variable to have unique value for every iteration and pass it to the url path, if yes please help me out.

Comment: You can use JMeter's Random function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328356/generate-random-number-variables-in-jmeter/45328753#45328753

Comment: Will this be unique for every iteration run for suppose I need to run 1 lakh iterations and i have set the random function limit to more than 1 lakh

Comment: for unique values you can use UUID https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193915/use-placeholder-or-generate-unique-id-using-wiremock-with-jmeter/62194070#62194070

Comment: Okay thank you, is ther a way we can pass like ${userid}+random function in url path  for every  iteration like for example userid is abcd and random function gives 10 then the value becomes abdc10 as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop Controller exposes `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) which returns the number of the current iteration. You can combine it with [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) so the combination of user and iteration would be more or less "unique" (within the bounds of test run)

[image]

But if you need to re-run the test most probably the data won't be accepted unless you clean up the database.

Also there is [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) which generates a [GUID](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)-like structure which is supposed to be unique

[image]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Actually I can't use it in the loop controller in loop count because I'll need to give a different variables in the loop count for needed iterations, i need to pass a variable unique value string only in the url path for every iteration and I can't use uuid function it's too large string for requirement, if there is any other way can you please suggest